# Typescript: map object values while keeping optional keys optional

Tags: javascript, typescript

E.g.:

```
type ObjectOf<T> = { [k: string]: T };

type MapObj<Obj extends ObjectOf<any>> = {
  [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends string
    ? 'string'
    : 'other';
};

type Foo = MapObj<{
  a?: 'a',
  b: 'b',
}>;
```

I want the type of `Foo` to be:

```
{
  a?: 'string',
  b: 'string',
}
```

But it's actually:

```
{
  a?: 'other' | undefined,
  b: 'string',
}
```

How can I fix this?

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2DAZgHgCoD4oC8UA3lANoDWAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmAujdlAL4DcAKEGhIUALIBDMPASZZUCAA9gEFgBNasRCjRZJLELnxFigqOQDSUVlAoQQAe3TaEXV2UsdFKtZrqMrGzmFlAA-FAA5PTM7JEhFjSRjsAAFhAMkUICwqLQAGKOjoQS0rKYZhaSYUmSkQA0IXBJcA2CvLj8QA

Comment: Does changing line 4 to this have the desired effect?  `[K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends string | (string | undefined)`

Comment: I get `a?: 'string' | undefined`, which I think is functionally the same as `a?: 'string'`. Thanks!

Comment: Turn off `strictNullChecks` in tsconfig.json ;)

Comment: I don't think there's a difference except in the display, see how: `type X = {
  a?: 'string',
  b: 'string',
};
const x: X = {
  a: undefined,
  b: 'string'
}` compiles fine

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have should work. Try setting this in tsconfig to narrow the type to what you want exactly:

```
"exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true
```

Without that option, I think it's going to add `undefined` to optional types regardless when it evals the type, since the setting is there to strictly enforce which properties can explicitly be set to `undefined` vs the property not being set at all.

See [tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes)